# JavaFX: How to enforce that a new style class is applied directly?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, listener, javafx-8

I am building an application which displays the results of different pathfinding algorithms on a graph. So every time a node is expanded i want it to be highlighted. For this reason i have a listener which is executed each time a node gets expanded. In addition there is the possibility to delay the process.

But the new style classes seem only to be rendered after the algorithm finishes.
On the other hand the console output is displayed correctly at runtime.

The code in question:

```
IDiGraphSearchListener<XYNode, CostEdge<XYNode>> listener = new IDiGraphSearchListener<XYNode, CostEdge<XYNode>>() {
    List<CostEdge<XYNode>> way;
    @Override
    public void onExpandNode(XYNode node, List<CostEdge<XYNode>> way) {
        if (this.way == null) {
            this.way = way;
        }
        System.out.println("Expanding");
        for (CostEdge<XYNode> costEdge : way) {
                graphPane.lookup("#"+costEdge.getId()).getStyleClass().add("visited");
                graphPane.lookup("#"+costEdge.getSource().getId()).getStyleClass().add("visited");
                graphPane.lookup("#"+costEdge.getTarget().getId()).getStyleClass().add("visited");
                System.out.println("Coloring-> EdgeID:"+costEdge.getId()+" From:"+costEdge.getSource().getId()+" To:"+costEdge.getTarget().getId());
        }       
        try {
            System.out.println("Sleeping");
            Thread.sleep((long) (pathfindingSpeedSlider.getValue()*1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //ToCatchOrNot
        }
    }
};
```

Sample output:

```
Algo: AStar
Expanding
Expanding
Coloring-> EdgeID:id20 From:id1 To:id2
Coloring-> EdgeID:id25 From:id1 To:id4
Coloring-> EdgeID:id45 From:id1 To:id9
Expanding
Coloring-> EdgeID:id21 From:id2 To:id3
Coloring-> EdgeID:id20 From:id1 To:id2
Coloring-> EdgeID:id25 From:id1 To:id4
Coloring-> EdgeID:id45 From:id1 To:id9
Expanding
Coloring-> EdgeID:id21 From:id2 To:id3
Coloring-> EdgeID:id20 From:id1 To:id2
Coloring-> EdgeID:id25 From:id1 To:id4
Coloring-> EdgeID:id45 From:id1 To:id9
Expanding
Coloring-> EdgeID:id21 From:id2 To:id3
Coloring-> EdgeID:id20 From:id1 To:id2
Coloring-> EdgeID:id46 From:id9 To:id5
Coloring-> EdgeID:id25 From:id1 To:id4
Coloring-> EdgeID:id45 From:id1 To:id9
Expanding
Coloring-> EdgeID:id21 From:id2 To:id3
Coloring-> EdgeID:id20 From:id1 To:id2
Coloring-> EdgeID:id46 From:id9 To:id5
Coloring-> EdgeID:id25 From:id1 To:id4
Coloring-> EdgeID:id28 From:id5 To:id6
Coloring-> EdgeID:id45 From:id1 To:id9
Expanding
Coloring-> EdgeID:id21 From:id2 To:id3
Coloring-> EdgeID:id20 From:id1 To:id2
Coloring-> EdgeID:id46 From:id9 To:id5
Coloring-> EdgeID:id25 From:id1 To:id4
Coloring-> EdgeID:id30 From:id6 To:id7
Coloring-> EdgeID:id28 From:id5 To:id6
Coloring-> EdgeID:id35 From:id6 To:id11
Coloring-> EdgeID:id45 From:id1 To:id9
getWay1
->id1/id9->id9/id5->id5/id6->id6/id7getWay2
Finish
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you observe is quite normal. You are setting new styles but they will not be executed before the next pulse. But because you are blocking the application thread with your code the next pulse will be delayed until you are done.

Comment: How would i prevent the pulse from getting delayed, too?

Comment: That's difficult to say because I don't understand what behaviour you actually want to achieve. The simple answer would just be to do all your processing on another thread.

Comment: I want to visualize how the algorithm advances through the graph. So after each expanding of a node the path get's highlighted and there should be a delay till the next node is expanded. I added some sample console output.

Comment: Ok, so you should definitely have a look at the JavaFX Concurrency tutorials. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm As I said before, you have to put the computation of your algorithm on a separate thread and do intermediate updates of your styles. These update calls have to be wrapped in Platform.runLater calls or you have to use the more advanced techinques of JavaFX concurrency.